# Filter table with select options (check if column is number or null) in React

Tags: reactjs, filtering

I am new at React and I am stuck.

I have a table with data from database. I want to filter that table with a select dropdown. I have mulitple "select-fields" that works fine, because the value in the dropdown matches the exact value in database. But now I just want to check if the column value is null or a number.

In my select options I just want three options (see left picture):

- All (Show all result. It is working)
- Missing number(is null in Database. Not working)
- Has number(Not working)

So the value in the table column (see right picture) I want to filter is either a number or null.

[image: [![The select options][1] [image: The table column]

Here is my code so far:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

//Column in table:
{
   Header: () => (<div>TableHead</div>),
   accessor: "accessorToDatabase",
   Cell: (props) => { return <div>{props?.cell?.value}</div> }
}

// The select dropdown and the table
<Col>
   <Label>Select Dropbox</Label>
      <Input type="select" onChange={handleChange('id', 'description')}>
         <option>All</option>
         <option value="false">Missing number</option>
         <option value="true">Has number</option>
      </Input>
</Col>

<Table columns={columns} data={filteredData} HandleRowData={HandleRowData} />

//The filter functions
const handleChange = name => ({ target: { value } }) => {
   filter[name] = (value === 'All') ? null : value

   if (checkProperties(filter)) {
     var filtered = state
   }
   else {
     var filtered = handleFilter(state, filter)
   }
   setFilteredData(filtered)
 }

 const handleFilter = (arr: Object[], filters: Object) => {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters)
     return arr.filter(eachObj => {
       return filterKeys.every(eachKey => {
         if (!filters[eachKey] || !filters[eachKey].length) {
           return true
         }
       })
    })
 }
```

I have tried with something like this, for looping through all values in the column, but without no success:

```
state.map(x=>((
    x.id> 0 ? x.id : null)))
```

Comment: what is state in your code?

Comment: I was wrong with my last comment, but seeing more code would be very helpful. Also, are you getting errors? Is it the wrong result or is no filter being applied at all?

Comment: @MichaelHoobler I got no errors, it's just that I don't get any filtered results. I have other "select-dropdowns" that filter correctly, but I think that is because the option value matches the value from database. For example: option value = 1, and id = 1 (in database)

Comment: @EtsukoSusui state is my array of data, right now with 4 objects that have id, name, comments for exemple

Comment: Could you share your code on codesandbox please.

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is used to transform one array of values/objects to another array with the same length but with transformed values/objects. What you want to use is `.filter`, which removes elements from an array but maintain the element structure.

To keep the ones that does not have an id:

```
array.filter(x => !x.id)
```

To keep the ones that has an id that is a number:

```
array.filter(x => !isNaN(x.id))
```

Comment: Where do you see `.map()`?

Comment: In the last part of her question, where she shows what she has done so far.

Comment: Yea it's `return arr.filter(eachObj => {...`, no? They also have an `.every` but that's used to figure out the return value for the filter.

Comment: I don't really understand.

Comment: Oh you're referring to the `state.map` (which I didn't even notice) and I'm referring to the `handleFilter` function. My bad.

Comment: Ah, good point! Yes the `.filter` seems better with just filtering the ones I want. But I still don't get them in the table..yet..

Answer (score 0):

A simple Array.prototype.filter should do the trick:

```
//removes all entries with an id of `0 || null || undefined`
state.filter(entry=>!!entry.id)
```

```
//removes all entries with an id of `null || undefined` but keeps the 0
state.filter(entry=>!!entry.id || entry.id === 0)
```

I would not recommend using `isNan`: as it internally tries to parse strings to check if they are numbers you might end up with some unexpected behaviors. It also goes wild with booleans, null and undefined.

See this link for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

## EDIT

Rereading your question it looks like you want

- all items
- items with an ID of type number
- items that are not numbers

Here is how you could implement that

```
  const [items,setItems]= useState(someItems)
  const [filter, setFilter]=useState('all')

  function handleChange(e){
    setFilter(e.target.value)
  }

  const filteredItems =  items.filter(item=>{
      if(filter === 'number')
         return typeof items === 'number'
      if(filter === 'no-number')
         return typeof item !== 'number'
      return true
  })

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value='all'>All</option>
        <option value='no-number'>Missing number</option>
        <option value="number">Has number</option>
      </select>

      <Table columns={columns} data={filteredData} HandleRowData={HandleRowData} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
```

Change the elements with the specific library you are using and you are good to go

Comment: Ok! I tried your code and it seems like it filter it correct, but I still dont get it into the Table yet..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using NaN, as it tries to parse strings. Instead, you can create an array and use the map function, in combination with the filter function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).